# Installing Windows 7 on an Asus EeePC 1008HA

Tags: windows-7, eee-pc

I'm planning to install Windows 7 on my Asus EeePC 1008HA netbook.

I heard that there were [some issues with RC1](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/GettingReadyforWindows7/thread/00fe1817-450e-4ed3-b178-8a732fd31f9f), but other than that have not had much luck finding help with this specific hardware.

The closest I've found is [this article](http://www.legitreviews.com/article/1023/1/) for the similar 1005HA.

I can find [XP drivers](http://support.asus.com/download/download.aspx?model=Eee%20PC%201008HA&os=17&SLanguage=en-us) and have them downloaded just in case. Also (obviously) I've backed up everything on the machine.

Anyone on here got any experience with Windows 7 on an Asus EeePC 1008HA?

Anyone know whether the reported issues with RC1 have been fixed by the RTM and driver updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so not quite seamless.

The install went smoothly enough.

Mounted iso using Microsoft's [XP utility](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/b/6/7b6abd84-7841-4978-96f5-bd58df02efa2/winxpvirtualcdcontrolpanel_21.exe), then copied it onto a fast SD HC card. Ran setup from there.

When this finished I found a nasty glitch. There's something wrong with the BIOS and the display. The Windows 7 starting graphic is too low - as if it thinks the 600 high screen is  768 instead. Then it goes black.

If I shut the lid - so it goes into standby, then press the power to wake it everything is fine again.

Everything else installed fine - I needed the Super Hybrid Engine Utility to get the ACPI drivers working, and I needed that to get the function keys working. Otherwise fine.

The one problem is this video bug on startup. Bloody annoying.

Much digging around has [lead me to a BIOS hack](http://forum.eeeuser.com/viewtopic.php?id=63510). Messing up stuff on disk is always fixable, but there's no way that I'm risking a hacked BIOS - far too high a risk of bricking the machine.

I think this bug is something to do with an updated BIOS - there appears to be a newer version [on the ftp site](ftp://ftp.asus.com.tw/pub/ASUS/EeePC/EeePC1008HA/1008HA-ASUS-1103.zip), but it isn't on the official download page - are they beta versions?

**Update:**
There's a potential batch file fix ([detailed here](http://forum.eeeuser.com/viewtopic.php?id=58307)) - although you need to run autologon (which I can't) in order for it to execute:

Just add a .bat file to startup:

```
displayswitch /extend
displayswitch /internal
```

**Update 2:**
The latest BIOS ([1103](ftp://ftp.asus.com.tw/pub/ASUS/EeePC/EeePC1008HA/1008HA-ASUS-1103.zip)) from the FTP site fixes the issue, but breaks the ACPI drivers and SHE.

Now I get an XP-style loading bar on boot, but it's quick and doesn't need the standby hack.

Until ASUS fix the SHE and ACPI drivers I'm going to have reduced battery life and the blue Fn keys not working.

**Update 3:**
Now works fine with:

- [BIOS 1103](ftp://ftp.asus.com.tw/pub/ASUS/EeePC/EeePC1008HA/1008HA-ASUS-1103.zip)
- [SHE 2.09](ftp://ftp.asus.com.tw/pub/asus/eeepc/Utility/ASUS-SHE-V2_09.zip)
- [Hotkeys and ACPI](ftp://ftp.asus.com.tw/pub/asus/eeepc/Utility/HotkeyService-1_13.zip)
- [Chipset driver](ftp://ftp.asus.com.tw/pub/asus/eeepc/Driver/Chipset-I945-9_1_1_1016.zip)

Answer (score 1):

A friend has this netbook.

I copied the root Windows 7 DVD, including ALL files to a blank formatted USB Stick and it installed Windows 7 fine, without any problems.

Drivers were all included with Windows 7, however I updated the Wireless ones to get better speed.

Answer (score 1):

Installed Windows 7 (RTM) with no issues at all.  It runs fast, smooth and without glitch.

HOWEVER...

I have been unsucessful in getting SHE (Super Hybrid Engine) to work at all. Also, the only FN keys that work for me are the Screen brightness functions.

I am currently using SetFSB to overclock the CPU.  I can run pretty stable at 1.81 GHz. I would rather use the ASUS SHE software.

I would love my FN keys to work.

It's a huge trade off to run the unstable xp for a few extra functions.   I am sure someone will amend the current drivers and apps out there.

Asus EEE Pc 1008HA
2 GB Ram
250GB 7200 WD HDD

Next upgrade for my 1008HA - 64 GB OCZ SSD drive 240 m/bit read and hoefully better battery life

Comment: 2GB RAM? So you've already customised it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much please add how to update Bios. eg on these lines: format sd card Fat16 (normal), copy new Bios to Sd Card, rename it 1008HA.rom, reboot with sd card in, External PSU connected, and press ALT F2 at reboot and that should do it. Peter